# Creating a Show/Hide Loop that Considers Radio Buttons and a Drop-down Menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, radio-button, hide, show

I am currently running a page that requires a drop-down menu and three radio buttons for user selections. Each time the user changes their selection, a div is displayed based on their selection while all other divs are hidden. My current JavaScript works, but it's a massive, and probably inefficient mess.

EX:

```
function enrollmentChange() {
            var enrollmentChoice = document.getElementById("enrollmentChoice");
            if (document.getElementById("onC").checked) {
                if (enrollmentChoice.options[enrollmentChoice.selectedIndex].text === "Please select enrollment status") {
                    document.getElementById("full-timeOn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("three-quarter-timeOn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("half-timeOn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("less-than-half-timeOn").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("full-timeOff").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("three-quarter-timeOff").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("half-timeOff").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("less-than-half-timeOff").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("full-timeComm").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("three-quarter-timeComm").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("half-timeComm").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("less-than-half-timeComm").style.display = "none";
                }
```

You can see it all here http://jsfiddle.net/5h3kL/2/.

Is there a way for me to condense this into some type of loop? I have played around with a few loops, but I'm uncertain of how to make the loop consider both the radio button selection and drop-down menu selection.

Comment: Put your html on fiddle too pls.

Comment: Okay, it's been updated in the main post. Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/5h3kL/2/. It does not work in the fiddle, but it works fine live.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might shorten things a bit:

```
function enrollmentChange() {
    var id = document.getElementById, // short hand
        choice = id("enrollmentChoice").options[id("enrollmentChoice").selectedIndex].text,
        which = id("onC").checked ? "On" :
                id("offC").checked ? "Off" :
                id("comm").checked ? "Comm" : "";

    if (which !== "") {
        ["On", "Off", "Comm"].forEach(function(w) {
            id("full-time" + w).style.display = "none";
            id("three-quarter-time" + w).style.display = "none";
            id("half-time" + w).style.display = "none";
            id("less-than-half-time" + w).style.display = "none";
        });

        if (choice === "Full Time (12 or More Credit Hours)") {
            id("full-time" + which).style.display = "block";
        } else if (choice === "Three-Quarter Time (9-11 Credit Hours)") {
            id("three-quarter-time" + which).style.display = "block";
        } else if (choice === "Half Time (6-8 Credit Hours)") {
            id("half-time" + which).style.display = "block";
        } else {
            id("less-than-half-time" + which).style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
var enrollmentChoice = document.getElementById("enrollmentChoice");
var arraymap = ['Please select enrollment status',''],
               ['Full Time (12 or More Credit Hours)','three-quarter-timeOn'],
               ['Half Time (6-8 Credit Hours)','half-timeOn'] ... ;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'radio') {
        for(var ii=0;ii<arraymap.length;ii++){
           if(arraymap[ii][0] == enrollmentChoice.options[enrollmentChoice.selectedIndex].text && arraymap[ii][1] == inputs[i].id){
              inputs[i].style.display = 'block';
           }else{
              inputs[i].style.display = 'none'; 
           }
        }
    }
}
```